# Eclipse Checkstyle Plugin 8.41.0 won't run

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

after upgrading to Checkstyle 8.41.0 in Eclipse 2021-3 the Checkstyle Plugin doesn't work anymore. In Preferences -> Checkstyle I get the following Message:

[image]

Here also the Stracktrace.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2021-05-07 17:30:27.528
!MESSAGE Could not create action delegate for id: net.sf.eclipsecs.ui.actions.CheckSelectedFilesAction
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.registry 4 1 2021-05-07 17:30:27.528
!MESSAGE Plug-in net.sf.eclipsecs.ui was unable to load class net.sf.eclipsecs.ui.actions.CheckSelectedFilesAction.
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle net.sf.eclipsecs.ui (80).
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:572)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:171)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:617)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:920)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.lambda$0(WorkbenchPlugin.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$40.run(Workbench.java:2667)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in net.sf.eclipsecs.ui.CheckstyleUIPlugin.start() of bundle net.sf.eclipsecs.ui.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:835)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:117)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @335c220d wants to load class org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display. A different class with the same name was previously loaded by org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @5e7b892b. (org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @5e7b892b, parent loader 'platform')
    at net.sf.eclipsecs.ui.CheckstyleUIPlugin.start(CheckstyleUIPlugin.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:814)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:806)
    ... 25 more
```

I also checked .p2\pool\plugins and I only have the plugin once. Also deleted all the old versions of the plugin but still nothing.

Anyone knows how I can fix this Problem?

Comment: If you have deleted something in `.p2\pool\plugins` and can't recover it, delete the whole `.p2` directory and reinstall Eclipse. It might be caused by a plugin you have installed (according to your screenshot you have a special dark theme plugin installed, which does some load time weaving to cheat the open source license of Eclipse and according to the log snippet loading of a class failed). So test it, whether it works without additional installed plugins.

Comment: I deleted old versions of checkstyle, because I read when a plugin is duplicated this exception may happen. It didn't help. I also had this error happen (only with checkstyle) no other plugin without the darkest dark theme plugin. 
I was looking for a solution without reinstalling eclipse. Installing everything new solves the problem yes. I'm looking for a fix that doesn't involve a clean install.

Comment: By deleting something in that folder you broke the installation. If you can't recover it, you have to reinstall Eclipse.

Comment: Eclipse is working and I only deleted old checkstyle plungin versions because the checkstyle plugin was not working. That was the solution I tried. The exception appeared after updating the plugin to 8.41. Sorry if I was unclear about it in my answers.

Comment: Never ever delete something from `.p2/pool/plugins`! This will definitely damage your installation and can cause issues running Eclipse or when installing/uninstalling stuff. Use the _Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details_ dialog or on the command line the [p2 director](https://help.eclipse.org/2021-03/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html) instead. You need to remove the rest (`.p2`) and reinstall everything from scratch. Unfortunately, there is no other way, but it won't take long (it should be faster than asking a question on Stack Overflow).